# How to add number by excluding the rows in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as below

| Stage | Target |
| --- | --- |
| Proposal | 15 |
| Approved | 11 |
| Negotiation | 8 |
| Closed | 5 |

I need to get the output as shown in the logic column

| Stage | Target | Logic |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Proposal | 15 | 11+8+5=24 |
| Approved | 11 | 8+5=13 |
| Negotiation | 8 | 5 |
| Closed | 5 | null or 5 |

Is it possible to achieve this? Kindly help to sort this.

Thanks

Comment: Yes it is , what version of mysql are you on?

Comment: I'm using a BI Tool which has SQL

Comment: Not what I asked and answer is dependent on version of mysql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       sum(target) over (order by field(stage, 'Proposal', 'Approved', 'Negotiation', 'Closed') desc
                         rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
                        ) as logic
from t;
```

This is basically a cumulative sum with special ordering logic.  The `rows` part simply excludes the current row.

Note:  If you wanted `0` for the final value, then I would suggest:

```
select t.*,
       sum(target) over (order by field(stage, 'Proposal', 'Approved', 'Negotiation', 'Closed') desc
                        ) - target as logic
from t;
```

Comment: It's working. Can you please tell me what does over( order by field) do?

Comment: @user12490809 . . . The `over` is a clause for window functions, which are needed for a cumulative sum.  The `field()` is a string function in MySQL that "looks up" a string value in a fixed set of values.